# Почему фиксированный DIV сдвигается при использовании fancybox? Как исправить ситуацию?

Tags: fancybox, css

При использовании для просмотра картинок скрипта FancyBox
фиксорованный ДИВ съезжает вправо на ширину полосы прокрутки.
[ПРИМЕР здесь.](http://lpsystem.ru/) Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Может как-то можно сделать, чтобы полоса прокрутки не пропадала?

Comment: Нашёл, что нужно "scrolling : 'yes'" прописать. А куда прописать, не понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // ваши другие параметры 
    'scrolling' : 'yes'
});
```

Comment: Вставил, но почему-то не работает.